# flock: cannot open lock file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-multipass

I am currently trying to build an image based on buildroot in `multipass` for `macOS` - however I encountered this error:

```
~/Home/Downloads/buildroot$ make -j 6
>>> host-pkgconf 1.6.3 Downloading
flock: cannot open lock file /home/ubuntu/Home/Downloads/buildroot/dl/pkgconf/.lock: Operation not permitted
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:190: /home/ubuntu/Home/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/host-pkgconf-1.6.3/.stamp_downloaded] Error 66
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2
```

even though the folder `dl` has every permission necessary:

```
~/Home/Downloads/buildroot$ ls -lsa | grep "dl"
  4 drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu     96 Dec 30 20:31 dl
```

Can someone give me a hint how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a file mounting problem. The mounted directory is not a real file system, and the operation of locking files is not supported. You need to copy the files to the vm linux directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).